# How to anchor to different sections in a page using the same element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a solution where I can anchor one single element to different sections.

```
<a href="#" id="navigate">Show more</a>

<div class="jumbotron" id="customer">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="jumbotron" id="features">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="jumbotron" id="contact">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above code, if I click on the `Show more` it should take me to `#customer`. And this button will remain at the bottom left of the page. Now if I click again on the same `Show more`, it should take me to the `#features`. Finally when I'm at `#contact`, the button should change to 'Go to top`.

Is there any jquery to implement this?

Comment: As a user, I dislike this approach. Clicking a link should always take me to the same content, not a different section every time.

Comment: @Blazemonger Actually this approach is for a single page website. Instead of scrolling to different sections, one single "Show more" button can be used to navigate to different sections.

Comment: And what happens when a user scrolls up to a previous section? Do you want "Show more" to take them to the next section in your list, or the next section after the one they're currently looking at?

Comment: Next section after the one they're currently looking at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/72aay/)

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="navigate" data-jump="0">Show more</a>

<div class="jumbotron" id="customer">
    <div class="container">CUSTOMER</div>
</div>
<div class="jumbotron" id="features">
    <div class="container">FEATURES</div>
</div>
<div class="jumbotron" id="contact">
    <div class="container">CONTACT</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    $("#navigate").click(function (e) {
        $(this).data("jump", $(this).data("jump")+1);
        switch ($(this).data("jump")) {
            case 1:
                $(document).scrollTop($("#customer").offset().top);
                break;
            case 2:
                $(document).scrollTop($("#features").offset().top);
                break;
            case 3:
                $(document).scrollTop($("#contact").offset().top);
                break;
            default:
                $(document).scrollTop(0);
                $(this).data("jump",0)
                break;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: What if I'm on the second section by scrolling the mouse and then click on the 'Show more' option? it should take me to the third section instead of the 2nd right?

Answer (score 1):

The code below works in normal browser, but when I tried to run it JSFiddler, then the order of the clicks was different there. Anyway, it works in normal browser:

```
$( "#navigate" ).on( "click", function() {

    var text = $( this ).text() 
    var href = $( this ).attr('href'); 

    if (href == "#") {
        $( this ).attr('href', '#customer'); 
    }
    else if (href == "#customer") {
        $( this ).attr('href', '#features');
    }
    else if ((href == "#features") && (text == "Show more")) {
        $( this ).text('Go to Top'); 
        $( this ).attr('href', '#contact');

    }
    else if ((href == "#contact") && (text == "Go to Top")) {
        $( this ).text('Show more'); 
        $( this ).attr('href', '#'); 
        $( this ).focus();

    }

});
```

In relation to Button's CSS positioning use fixed:

```
a {
   position:fixed;
   bottom:1px;
   left:1px;
}
```

[More info](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Each time clicking the button, find the current value, according to the value of `href`, update the `href` attribute for what you want.

For example, right now the `href` is navigating to "customer", and then after clicking, read out the value of `href`, and we found that it's pointing to `customer`, then we should update the value of `href` to the `features` section.

Comment: But how do we implement this in jquery?

Comment: That's basic stuff, you should go over a simple jQuery tutorial for that first. Basically you should implement a onClick function for the `a` tag, and looking for the `href` attribute using `$("a#navigate").attr("href")`

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea might be this:

```
$("#navigate").attr('href', '#customer');
$("#navigate").click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('href') == '#customers'){
        $(this).attr('href', '#features');
    }else if($(this).attr('href') == '#features'){
        $(this).attr('href', '#contact');
    }else {
        $(this).attr('href', '#customer');
    }
});
```